# how can i add a full screen image view for all images in grid view using android

Tags: android, gridview, onclicklistener, picasso

I am using picasso to load images from url into gridview. Now i want to add a onclick full screen image view for all the images in grid view .
Can some one help me out.
Thank You[I am using this example to load iamges fromurl into gridview using picasso](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/picasso-getting-started-simple-loading)

Comment: You mean something like and gallery app?

Comment: Maybe use onItemClickListener with a fullscreen Dialog

Comment: its like wallpaper app

Comment: can you provide any code example @BenvanHartingsveldt

Comment: gridview.setItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

@Override
public void onItemClick(Object... paramsHere){
 //start the dialog with specific image
}

});

You could also start a new activity instead of a dialog.

Comment: I am able to toast text   but unable to to load image using intent so help me out @BenvanHartingsveldt

Comment: You can send the url path in a Intent Extra and then load the image by that url in your new activity.

Comment: thank you it works....@BenvanHartingsveldt

Comment: Hey i wanted to add download option in that full screen activity to save the image into gallery once clicked on download option. how can i do that. Help me out. @BenvanHartingsveldt

Comment: Your new activity knows the URL, so you can make a menu button with a download icon. This button wil trigger a onMenuItemClicked function and download the image with the DownloadManager.

Comment: Thanks its working  @BenvanHartingsveldt